# Using Mocks for Design Data in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, moq, castle-dynamicproxy

I have a WPF module that gets data in form of interfaces, e.g. `ICustomer`. The real Customer object is defined in another module, that I can't reference in the WPF module because of lose coupling.

Since we want design data in our projects, and I want to avoid to write Fakes for every entity, I thought that using Moq would help here, so I made a small example:

```
public MainVM()
{
    if (IsInDesignMode)
    {
        var c1 = new Mock<ICustomer>();
        c1.SetupAllProperties();
        c1.FirstName = "John";
        c1.LastName = "Doe";

        Customers = new List<ICustomer>
        {
            c1.Object,
        };
    }
}
```

In the view I bring in the datacontext and do:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:MainVM, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

The problem now is, that the line in the view throws me an exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.ICustomerProxy_5' to 'Prototype.Data.ICustomer'
```

How can I get rid of this error? Is there some workaround?

Comment: Interesting use for Moq.  Also technically in MVVM you shouldn't expose your model anywhere.  The list of `ICustomer` objects (if it is indeed a model entity) violates that; you should wrap them in customer view models.

Comment: Well... as I read this is quite the debate, whether it is kosher to do that or not. We think it's OK, weighted against the immense work the view models would generate. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't think the work is immense, it's just a wrapper class.  The VM would let you add actions/other properties to your entity for display purposes if needed, giving you current and future flexibility.  But MVVM is a style, not a ruleset.  Do what works for you!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865810/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-castle-proxies-xproxy-to-type-x-in-wpf-designe

Comment: I saw that one, but I am clueless of what he says he's doing with the assemblies in his answer... :/

Comment: `in MVVM you shouldn't expose your model anywhere` uh....  And in the linked question, it seems like some assembly loading weirdness is the cause, and autoincrementing the assembly version helps fix this.  So open up AssemblyInfo.cs and use the `*` thingie in your version number to auto increment the build/revision numbers, like `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("5.0.*")]`

Comment: You seem to be missing an `.Object` when you set the properties `FirstName` and `LastName`?